# How to configure a PHP extension for multiple PHP versions?

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-extension, php-amqp

Using ondrej repository on Ubuntu Focal, I have installed PHP from `5.6` to `7.4`.

When I install an extension, for example `php-amqp` in my case with `apt install php-amqp`, the extension is only configured for the default PHP version `7.4`.

When looking for `amqp.so` in my system, it's only available in the PHP `7.4` extension folder `/usr/lib/php/20190902`.

How can I make it available in all my PHP version (and same for others extension like `php-geoip` for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so dumb. When I upgraded to Ubuntu Focal, ondrej's repository was not ready for it, stuck with Eoan.

Now, I have update the repository because Focal is available and after a `apt update && apt upgrade`, all my PHP extensions have been reconfigured and are available in all my PHP versions.